# Accessing buttons settings via arrays

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to access the button options via array but i get a null exception

first of all i'd like to access via arrays the settings like i did below.

Separately detect if a button in the arrays has been clicked.

```
  dim buttonRow0() as buttons = {button1,button2,button3}
  dim buttonRow1() as buttons = {button4,button5,button6}
  dim buttonRow2() as buttons = {button7,button8,button9}

  dim buttonRows() as object = {buttonRow0,buttonRow1,buttonRow2}

  buttonsRows(1)(1).BackColor = Color.Red
```

set button5 color to red

i get:

> System.NullReferenceException, object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: you are using vb.net?

Comment: and it is typo buttonsRow instead of buttonRows ?

Comment: what problem found ?

Comment: @MangeshAuti i mean i've corrected the errors in the script

Comment: what did you try to solve the problem? please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @swe I've posted how to fix the problem below!

Comment: Isn't a list of buttons easier?

Comment: @CruleD can you show us below your option? remember is vb.net

Answer (score 0):

fix:
Note you can simply create an array as and where you need to if you like. There's very little overhead to it so it's not a big deal. For instance, you might have an event handler that is executed multiple times and you might create the array in that event handler, thus multiple arrays will be created and discarded. No big deal. You can also just create the one array and reuse it by assign it to a member variable. There's a bit of a gotcha when doing that though. You can't do this:
vb.net Code:

```
Private buttons As Button() = {Button1, Button2, Button3}
```

because that code will be executed before the form's constructor and thus before the Buttons are created. That means that you'll end up with an array containing `Nothing`, `Nothing` and `Nothing`. You need to create the array and assign it to the field after the constructor is executed, so in the Load event handler:
vb.net Code:

```
Private buttons As Button()

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    buttons = {Button1, Button2, Button3}
End Sub
```